# In Codeigniter : How to give the image path in external js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Path for image- assets/rating/star.png
Now how to give this path in external js
I have also loaded the url helper.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#1_star").hover(function(){
            $("#1_star").attr("src","Path for image");
        });
});
```

I am doing this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#1_star").hover(function(){
            $("#1_star").attr("src","<?php echo base_url('assets/rating/star.png');?>");
        });
});
```

Comment: You're doing right, whats the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#1_star").hover(function(){
         var base_url = window.location.origin;
         $("#1_star").attr("src",base_url + '/assets/rating/star.png');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in your html page add

```
<input type="hidden" id="document" name="document" value="<?php echo base_url('assets/rating/star.png');?>">
```

In your js file

```
var path= $('#document').val();
alert(path);

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#1_star").hover(function(){
            $("#1_star").attr("src",path);
        });
});
```

try and let me know it works or not